# How to use JDBC from within the Spark/Scala interpreter (REPL)?

Tags: scala, jdbc, apache-spark

I'm attempting to access a database in the Scala interpreter for Spark, but am having no success.

First, I have imported the DriverManager, and I have added my SQL Server JDBC driver to the class path with the following commands:

```
scala> import java.sql._
import java.sql._

scala> :cp sqljdbc41.jar
```

The REPL crashes with a long dump message:

```
Added 'C:\spark\sqljdbc41.jar'.  Your new classpath is:
";;C:\spark\bin\..\conf;C:\spark\bin\..\lib\spark-assembly-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar;;C:\spark\bin\..\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.1.jar;C:\spark\bin\..\lib\datanucleus-core-3.2.2.jar;C:\spark\bin\..\lib\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.1.jar;;C:\spark\sqljdbc41.jar"
Replaying: import java.sql._
error:
     while compiling: <console>
        during phase: jvm
     library version: version 2.10.4
    compiler version: version 2.10.4
  reconstructed args:

  last tree to typer: Apply(constructor $read)
              symbol: constructor $read in class $read (flags: <method> <triedcooking>)
   symbol definition: def <init>(): $line10.$read
                 tpe: $line10.$read
       symbol owners: constructor $read -> class $read -> package $line10
      context owners: class iwC -> package $line10

== Enclosing template or block ==

Template( // val <local $iwC>: <notype>, tree.tpe=$line10.iwC
  "java.lang.Object", "scala.Serializable" // parents
  ValDef(
    private
    "_"
    <tpt>
    <empty>
  )
    ...

== Expanded type of tree ==

TypeRef(TypeSymbol(class $read extends Serializable))

uncaught exception during compilation: java.lang.AssertionError
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Tried to find '$line10' in 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-28055904-e7d2-4052-9354-ae3769266cb4' but it is not a directory
That entry seems to have slain the compiler.  Shall I replay
your session? I can re-run each line except the last one.
```

I am able to run a Scala program with the driver and everything works just fine.

How can I initialize my REPL to allow me to access data from SQL Server through JDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the interactive `:cp` command does not work in Windows.  But I found that if I launch the spark shell using the following command, the JDBC driver is loaded and available:

```
C:\spark> .\bin\spark-shell --jars sqljdbc41.jar
```

In this case, I had copied my jar file into the C:\spark folder.

(Also, one can also get help to see other commands available at launch using `--help`.)